# Page numbers using leaflet class

Tags: page-numbering, leaflet

I'm attempting to typeset a very short paper as a pamphlet, and am doing so using the [leaflet class](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/leaflet).

Using it, a two-page document is produced, each page having three columns, each treated as a page (e.g. a page break induces the same behavior as a column break would do in a multi-column document.)

The class does not be default have page numbers (1-6), and they are not produced using the `fancyhdr` package.

How could I obtain footers with centered page numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Searching the manual did not provide an answer, as the answer is upside down on page 2. But it was there.

Include `\pagestyle{plain}` to set all pages to have normal page numbers.

These will be positioned a little high, so I opted for using the `fancyhdr` package. To get rid of the horizontal rule, moved the page number down a bit and make smaller, I included the following in my preamble:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}            
\fancyhf{}                                         % Blank out the default header
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}                 % Remove horizontal rule in header
\fancyfoot[C]{\smaller $\phantom{.}_{\thepage}$}   % Custom footer text
\pagestyle{fancy}                                  % Apply to all pages
```

To not get a page number on the title page, I put `\thispagestyle{empty}` after `\maketitle`.